# Нужно удалить пробелы после запятных и построить график

Tags: python, pandas

У меня такой вопрос. У меня есть столбец в xlxs. В нём содержится несколько типов индустрий. Мне нужно построить график. Индрустрия - по оси абсцисс. Её количество - ось ординат.

столбец выглядит так (его часть):

```
industry_type
EdTech, Education, Secondary Education
Analytics, Artificial Intelligence, E-Commerce, Retail
Asset Management, Financial Services, Real Estate, Real Estate Investment
CRM, Customer Service, InsurTech
Apps, Children, Consumer, Content Creators, Digital Entertainment, EBooks, Education, Subscription Service, Video
Delivery Service, Drones, Logistics, Robotics
Apps, Consumer, E-Commerce, Group Buying, Marketplace, Social Shopping
Database, Information Technology, SaaS, Software
```

я посчитал количество каждых типов с помощью:
`Counter(','.join(df['industry_type']).replace('', '').split(','))`

вывод:

```
Counter({'EdTech': 3,
         ' Education': 21,
         ' Secondary Education': 1,
         'Analytics': 59,
         ' Artificial Intelligence': 23,
         ' E-Commerce': 67,
         ' Retail': 34,
         'Asset Management': 10,
         ' Financial Services': 128,
         ' Real Estate': 16,
         ' Real Estate Investment': 5,
         'CRM': 9,
         ' Customer Service': 9,
         ' InsurTech': 13,
         'Apps': 38,
         ' Children': 3,
         ' Consumer': 4,
         ' Content Creators': 1,
         ' Digital Entertainment': 5,
         ' EBooks': 1,
         ' Subscription Service': 12,
         ' Video': 11,
```

существуют пробелы в словах, если они идут не первыми в строке. И не знаю, как построить график этих данных. Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: немного не в тему, но зачем у вас replace('', '') ? опечатки там нет ?

Comment: replace('', '') и replace('','') ничем не отличаются в выводе у меня, к сожалению. Не могу понять причину

Comment: вас не об этом спросили. почему у вас `replace('','')` , а не `replace(' ', '')`?

Comment: при использовании `replace(' ', '')` Удаляются все пробелы. Например, Asset Management превратится в AssetManagement

Comment: воспроизводимый пример данных есть?

Comment: Вообще что-то непонятное. зачем вам Counter, если у вас есть pandas? приведите воспроизводимый пример данных в вопросе и желаемый результат.